# Is there a word similar to "encircled", but meaning "to surround in a rectangle or a quadrilateral", instead of a circle?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

When I show screenshots and I want those who see the screenshot to focus on the area of the screenshot I marked as surrounded with a quadrilateral (usually a rectangle), I would say "see the area *encircled* in red".

It turns out that this is an incorrect usage of the word "[encircled](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/encircle)", as it means "to surround somebody/something completely in a *circle*".

Is there a word similar to "encircled", but meaning "to surround in a rectangle or a quadrilateral", instead of a circle?

Answer (score 17):

*framed* - put in a frame, usually rectangular. Framed in red would be probably what you need.

Answer (score 9):

*Boxed-in* - enclosed in or as if in a box.

Comment: I thought of _fenced-in_, too – although that would be a terrible choice for talking about which part of a screen was highlighted. It could work for a piece of real estate, though.

Comment: Or just *boxed area*.

Comment: I think *boxed area* works well, or even *highlighted area* can be used in that context.

Comment: Even _enclosed in_ , which you included in the definition for _boxed in_ would work well.

Answer (score 5):

Without being so precise, you could be less precise, and speak about the **highlighted** area, or **focussed**...

With more information, you could say, "Remember the name in the blue highlighted area," if you surrounded it with a blue rectangle.

Answer (score 4):

*Encircle* can be used to mean *[surround something or someone completely](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/encircle)* without the object being a circle. You can also use *[bound](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/bound_2)* for your purpose.

Comment: True, but the OP's problem is that he would want to contrast with a circle used for the purpose.

Answer (score -1):

enrectangled, ensquared. If you're willing to, Will-like, create wording anew?
(Ay 'pologise 'n a'vance m'ladies an' gents).

Comment: While creative, your neologisms are not conducive to an answer.  Please do take a [tour] of the site and review the [FAQ] for what goes into an answer.  Enjoy!